# Open Epub from uri ActivityNotFoundException Error Android

Tags: android, file-io, uri, activitynotfoundexception

Im open a epub file when I press a button, but when my android don´t have any epub reader, show an toast saying please install epub reader, but my code not works, and stopp my app saying the app stop unexpectedly.

```
Button leer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btnleer);
        leer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                File file = new File("/sdcard/Mi Biblioteca/"+nomb+".epub");
                Intent intentreadf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intentreadf.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/epub+zip");
                intentreadf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intentreadf);

                try {
                    startActivity(intentreadf);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "favor descargar lector epub.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} 
            }

            });
```

Comment: you need an application for open epub

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `startActivity(intentreadf);` command right after `intentreadf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`. It gets called before your `try-catch` block, and hence throws an exception.

Comment: oh! I had not realized that he was starting the activity before the try, thank you very much for your help! I owe you one!